# Bluebird .then method

Tags: promise, bluebird

The Bluebird docs for the .call method have a [code sample](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#callstring-propertyname--dynamic-arg---promise) labeled, "Chaining lo-dash or underscore methods".

What is the purpose of the chained `.then(_)` in the code snippet below?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

...

var _ = require("lodash");
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

fs.readdirAsync(".").then(_) <-- ???
    .call("groupBy", function(fileName) {
        return fileName.charAt(0);
    })

...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read in [the docs](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) what the `_` function does

Comment: Bergi - Thanks for the links to the Underscore docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In underscore the _ identifier is a function as well as a namespace.

Doing .then returns the result of the passed function.

Calling the `_` function starts a underscore chain, any consecutive actions happen on the object passed. It starts a chain with the result of readdirAsync.

Comment: (Sorry for short answer, on mobile and didn't want to leave you hanging - let me know if you'd like me to elaborate on something)

Comment: Benjamin - Thanks for your answer. Brevity is a good thing... :-)